# Django Rest Framework Multi-tier Nested Serialization

Tags: django, serialization, nested, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I have four models I am trying to serialize into one response. I have managed to get the top three models to work as desired and I can get the bottom two to work as desired but I cannot for the life of me get the last relationship to work as desired within one serialized response. Appreciate any thoughts as at this point, I don't know if I should be focused on my serializers or the view.

```
models.py:

class Survey(models.Model):
    survey_name = models.CharField('survey name', max_length=100)
    survey_type = models.CharField('survey type', max_length=1)
    survey_category = models.CharField('survey category', max_length=1)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, through='SurveyDetail')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)

class SurveyDetail(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, verbose_name='survey identifier')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, verbose_name='question identifier')
    question_number = models.IntegerField('question number', default=0)
    question_type = models.CharField('question type', max_length=1, default='M')
    question_quiz_mode = models.BooleanField('quiz mode', default=False)
    question_attributes = JSONField('question attributes', null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField('question', max_length=200)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='parent question identifier')
    answer_number = models.IntegerField('answer number', default=0)
    answer_text = models.CharField('answer text', max_length=200)
    correct_answer = models.BooleanField('quiz answer', default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)
```

A Survey has Questions which is a Many-to-Many relationship through SurveyDetails. A Question can exist on multiple Surveys in different formats which is the reason for the additional fields introduced in SurveyDetails. The final piece is that Answers belong to one-and-only-one Question.

```
serializers.py:

class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('id', 'answer_number', 'answer_text', 
                  'correct_answer')

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = AnswerSerializer(source='answer_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'question_text', 'answers')

class SurveyDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='question.id')
    text = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='question.question_text')

    class Meta:
        model = SurveyDetail
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'question_number', 'question_type',
                  'question_quiz_mode', 'question_attributes')

class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions=SurveyDetailSerializer(source='surveydetail_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ('id', 'survey_name', 'survey_type', 'survey_category', 'questions')
```

I am only working with two views for now just trying to obtain the entire Survey in a response.

```
views.py

class SurveyList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Survey.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SurveySerializer

class QuestionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

When I invoke my /surveys url, I manage to get everything about the survey including the Question text from the Question model. However, I cannot get the Answers to render inline with their Question.

```
/surveys response:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "survey_name": "Test",
        "survey_type": "T",
        "survey_category": "T",
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "text": "Does this work?",
                "question_number": 1,
                "question_type": "M",
                "question_quiz_mode": false,
                "question_attributes": null
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "text": "Does this still work?",
                "question_number": 2,
                "question_type": "M",
                "question_quiz_mode": false,
                "question_attributes": null
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "text": "Why?",
                "question_number": 3,
                "question_type": "M",
                "question_quiz_mode": false,
                "question_attributes": null
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "text": "Really?",
                "question_number": 4,
                "question_type": "M",
                "question_quiz_mode": false,
                "question_attributes": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I execute a view on Question, I can get the Question and Associated Answers.

```
/questions response:
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "question_text": "Why?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "answer_number": 1,
                "answer_text": "Because",
                "correct_answer": false
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "answer_number": 2,
                "answer_text": "Just Does",
                "correct_answer": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "question_text": "Really?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "answer_number": 1,
                "answer_text": "Yes",
                "correct_answer": false
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "answer_number": 2,
                "answer_text": "No",
                "correct_answer": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question_text": "Does this still work?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "answer_number": 1,
                "answer_text": "Yes",
                "correct_answer": false
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "answer_number": 2,
                "answer_text": "No",
                "correct_answer": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question_text": "Does this work?",
        "answers": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "answer_number": 1,
                "answer_text": "Yes",
                "correct_answer": false
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "answer_number": 2,
                "answer_text": "No",
                "correct_answer": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I am ultimately looking to achieve is the Answers to be inline with their Questions when /surveys is requested. Something similar to this:

```
Desired Response:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "survey_name": "Test",
        "survey_type": "T",
        "survey_category": "T",
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "text": "Does this work?",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "answer_number": 1,
                        "answer_text": "Yes",
                        "correct_answer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "answer_number": 2,
                        "answer_text": "No",
                        "correct_answer": false
                    }
                ],
                "question_number": 1,
                "question_type": "M",
                "question_quiz_mode": false,
                "question_attributes": null
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "text": "Does this still work?",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "answer_number": 1,
                        "answer_text": "Yes",
                        "correct_answer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "answer_number": 2,
                        "answer_text": "No",
                        "correct_answer": false
                    }
                ],
                "question_number": 2,
                "question_type": "M",
                "question_quiz_mode": false,
                "question_attributes": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I appreciate any insight and advice on the topic. I am sure it is something pretty straight forward that I am missing but I am relatively new to DRF. After 3 days of googling and researching, I figured it was time to ask the experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class SurveyDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='question.id')
    text = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='question.question_text')
    answers = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SurveyDetail
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'answers', 'question_number', 'question_type',
              'question_quiz_mode', 'question_attributes')

    def get_answers(self, obj):
        return AnswerSerializer(obj.question.answer_set.all(), many=True).data
```

Comment: Thank you @Jahongir Rahmonov . I gave that a try but I am receiving the following error. Exception Value: 
'SurveyDetail' object has no attribute 'answers'. I thought the SerializerMethodField() would add a field similar to the ReadOnlyField but the behavior seems to be different.

Comment: @Andrew try `answer_set`: `obj.answer_set.all()`

Comment: sorry to be dense, but where exactly would you want me to try this snippet?

Comment: I cut and paste you exact code just to be sure I wasn't missing something but still receiving the "no attribute" exception

Comment: @Andrew which `attribute` this time? Can you post the error message?

Comment: @Andrew I just updated the answer. Can you try that? I added `question` to have `obj.question.answer_set.all()`

Comment: thank you thank you thank you!!!! The last change introducing "question" worked like a charm!